# How to get the 'Unread' Tab in Outlook 2019

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2019, unread-mail

I have choices between "Focused" and "Other" but no way of showing only my unread e-mails.

I would like the original 'Unread' tab to be displayed.

Answer (score 3):

On the far-right side of the window, you can choose how to sort your mail.

[image]

Select:

```
'Show Focused Inbox'
```

This will update your tab options

From `Focused | Other`

To `All | Unread`

As shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also set this via the following settings:

1. In Outlook client, select the View tab.
2. Click Show Focused Inbox.

Reference: [Folders Contain 'Focused' and 'Other' Types](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9f87e3be-3082-4824-9114-493bc18f7902/folders-contain-focused-and-other-types?forum=outlook)

Answer (score 0):

This has changed in the latest Outlook update (as of Feb 26, 2021).

Now, right click From header, select Arrange By, turn off Show in Groups:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8cH0.png